# Bug when reading password with confirmation and retries in a loop

Tags: c#, validation, passwords

EDIT: The problem I am facing is that I enter an incorrect password to confirm previous password and it works since it is the first try. The max is 3 tries. During 2nd and 3rd try even if password is correct it will say invalid password.
I do not want that

I know I am missing something very trivial but I cannot manage to find it. This is the code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string username = "";
        string pass = "";
        string confirmPass = "";
        Console.Write("Enter username: ");
        username = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("Enter your password: ");
        ConsoleKeyInfo key;

        do
        {
            key = Console.ReadKey(true);

            // Backspace Should Not Work
            if (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Backspace && key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                pass += key.KeyChar;
                Console.Write("*");
            }
            else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && pass.Length > 0)
            {
            pass = pass.Substring(0, (pass.Length - 1));
            Console.Write("\b \b");
            }

        // Stops Receving Keys Once Enter is Pressed
        } while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);

        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Confirm your password: ");
        ConsoleKeyInfo confirmKey;

        int retryCount = 3;

        string finalPass = "";
        do{


            confirmKey = Console.ReadKey(true);

            // Backspace Should Not Work
            if (confirmKey.Key != ConsoleKey.Backspace && confirmKey.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                confirmPass += confirmKey.KeyChar;
                Console.Write("*");
            }
            else if (confirmKey.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && pass.Length > 0)
            {
                confirmPass = confirmPass.Substring(0, (confirmPass.Length - 1));
                Console.Write("\b \b");
            }
            //

            // Stops Receving Keys Once Enter is Pressed
        } while ((confirmKey.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter));

        //Console.WriteLine("");
        //string confirmPass = "";

        do
        {
            if (confirmPass != pass)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Re-enter Password: (" + retryCount + " tries remaining)");

                do
                {


                   confirmKey = Console.ReadKey(true);

                    // Backspace Should Not Work
                    if (confirmKey.Key != ConsoleKey.Backspace && confirmKey.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
                    {
                        confirmPass += confirmKey.KeyChar;
                        Console.Write("*");
                    }
                    else if (confirmKey.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && pass.Length > 0)
                    {
                        confirmPass = confirmPass.Substring(0, (confirmPass.Length - 1));
                        Console.Write("\b \b");
                    }
                    //

                    // Stops Receving Keys Once Enter is Pressed
                } while ((confirmKey.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter));
                retryCount--;

            }

            else if (confirmPass == pass)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter password to log in :");
                finalPass = Console.ReadLine();
                if (finalPass == pass)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Login Successful. Welcome " + username + "!");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Test Successful. Press Enter to quit.");
                }
            }
            if (retryCount == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exceeded number of tries!!");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        } while (confirmPass != pass && retryCount != 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't even told us what the problem is. Please come up with a [Short, Self Contained, Correct, Example](http://sscce.org/) instead of simply pasting your entire program here and asking us to fix it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, this is what I came up with:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string username = "";
    string pass = "";
    string confirmPass = "";
    Console.Write("Enter username: ");
    username = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.Write("Enter your password: ");
    ConsoleKeyInfo key;

    do
    {
        key = Console.ReadKey(true);

        // Backspace Should Not Work
        if (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Backspace && key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
        {
            pass += key.KeyChar;
            Console.Write("*");
        }
        else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && pass.Length > 0)
        {
            pass = pass.Substring(0, (pass.Length - 1));
            Console.Write("\b \b");
        }
        // Stops Receving Keys Once Enter is Pressed
    } while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);

    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("Confirm your password: ");
    ConsoleKeyInfo confirmKey;

    int retryCount = 3;

    string finalPass = "";
    do
    {
        confirmKey = Console.ReadKey(true);
        // Backspace Should Not Work
        if (confirmKey.Key != ConsoleKey.Backspace && confirmKey.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
        {
            confirmPass += confirmKey.KeyChar;
            Console.Write("*");
        }
        else if (confirmKey.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && pass.Length > 0)
        {
            confirmPass = confirmPass.Substring(0, (confirmPass.Length - 1));
            Console.Write("\b \b");
        }
        // Stops Receving Keys Once Enter is Pressed
    } while ((confirmKey.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter));

    do
    {
        if (confirmPass != pass)
        {
            confirmPass = "";
            Console.WriteLine("Re-enter Password: (" + retryCount + " tries remaining)");

            do
            {
                confirmKey = Console.ReadKey(true);

                // Backspace Should Not Work
                if (confirmKey.Key != ConsoleKey.Backspace && confirmKey.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {
                    confirmPass += confirmKey.KeyChar;
                    Console.Write("*");
                }
                else if (confirmKey.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && pass.Length > 0)
                {
                    confirmPass = confirmPass.Substring(0, (confirmPass.Length - 1));
                    Console.Write("\b \b");
                }
                // Stops Receving Keys Once Enter is Pressed
            } while ((confirmKey.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter));
            retryCount--;
        }
        else if (confirmPass == pass)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter password to log in :");
            finalPass = Console.ReadLine();
            if (finalPass == pass)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Login Successful. Welcome " + username + "!");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Test Successful. Press Enter to quit.");
                Console.ReadLine();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (retryCount == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exceeded number of tries!!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    } while (retryCount != 0);
}
```

Basically I made the following changes:

1. When you enter that last `do` loop, and enter the first `if` statement, I set `confirmPass = "";`. This is the reason your code did not do that part initially, because you were appending their **new** `confirmPass` to the original. Thus, if they typed `password`, then `password2`, then to retry they typed `password`, `confirmPass` was `password2password`.
2. After changing this, the flow did not work correctly, so I removed the `confirmPass != pass &&` bit from that `while`. This allowed you to get to the `elseif` portion in that loop.
3. Still, I assume this was a bit wrong as once you hit that `elseif` it would infinite loop. So I told it to `break` inside that `elseif` which **kills** that `do/while` loop.

If this solution is not correct, please **clarify your requirements** so that we may better assist you.

Comment: Thankyou for all the replies, bug spotting and suggestions. Really appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is rather convoluted, which is why it will be much harder to spot any errors. You should really learn how to use sub routines (i.e. functions), so that you don't have to repeat blocks of code that do the same thing over and over again (like reading a password).

If we were to refactor your code a little bit, by moving those repeated parts out into a method named `ReadPassword`, like this:

```
public static string ReadPassword()
{
    var pass = "";
    while (true)
    {
        var key = Console.ReadKey(true);
        if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
            // Stop Receving Keys Once Enter is Pressed
            break;

        // Backspace Should Not Work
        if (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Backspace)
        {
            pass += key.KeyChar;
            Console.Write("*");
        }
        else if (pass.Length > 0)
        {
            pass = pass.Substring(0, (pass.Length - 1));
            Console.Write("\b \b");
        }
    }
    return pass;
}
```

And used it to replace all those `do ... while` loops used for reading a password, **without changing anything else in your code** (so the bugs are still there):

```
public static void Main(params string[] args)
{
    string username = "";
    string pass = "";
    string confirmPass = "";
    Console.Write("Enter username: ");
    username = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.Write("Enter your password: ");
    pass = ReadPassword(); // changed to function call

    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("Confirm your password: ");
    int retryCount = 3;
    string finalPass = "";
    confirmPass = ReadPassword(); // changed to function call

    do
    {
        if (confirmPass != pass) // <==== this is performed before the "else"
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Re-enter Password: (" + retryCount + " tries remaining)");
            confirmPass = ReadPassword(); // changed to function call
            retryCount--;
        }
        else if (confirmPass == pass) // <==== "else": bug
        {
            // Bug: it will only get here, if the confirmed password 
            // was entered correctly the first time
            Console.WriteLine("Enter password to log in :");
            finalPass = Console.ReadLine();
            if (finalPass == pass)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Login Successful. Welcome " + username + "!");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Test Successful. Press Enter to quit.");
            }
            // else <==== now what?
        }
        if (retryCount == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exceeded number of tries!!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    } while (confirmPass != pass && retryCount != 0);
}
```

Now the bugs become much easier to spot. I highlighted them using `<===` in the comments. I will leave it to you to figure out what is wrong, and how you can fix it.